# "Attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Tags: python, django

When i want to save this django file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views  

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index)
]
```

I get an error :

"Attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

What should I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your assignment to `urlpatterns` to this:

```
urlpatterns = [path('index/', views.index, name='main-view')]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that some import syntaxes are Django-specific, which the interpreter (like pylint) cannot recognize unless they are installed along with Django and that require some extra work. If the server works but the compiler doesn't let you run it, simply disable whatever interpreter you have or switch to another IDE.

But always remember, in a Django application, it should work out like this (NOT the main folder where the `settings.py` is located in):

```
|-app_name
|__ __init__.py
|__ admin.py
|__ apps.py
|__ models.py
|__ urls.py
|__ views.py
```

As long as your files are structured like this, `from . import views` should work.